# mouse movement causes Gazebo death

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I repost this from the DRC web site. I have had the same problem, and avoid moving my mouse over the Gazebo window as much as possible.
I realize this sounds like a totally bogus bug report and I am engaging in voodoo computer science, but there is no core dump or other evidence I can provide. Perhaps an instrumented version of Gazebo could be created that reports more information about why it quits or crashes.

From rel_dude, posted at
http://forum.theroboticschallenge.org/index.php?board=6.0
I have tried installed the DRC Simulator using these installation instructions: http://gazebosim.org/wiki/InstallDRC
However, the simulator keeps crashing. It seems to happen mostly when hovering over the control menu (with the rotation controls, for instance) although not exclusively.
The terminal shows: "Warning [gazebo_main.cc:57] escalating to SIGKILL on server"
Originally I thought it might be a problem with nVidia drivers although it seems to happen on non-nVidia cards as well.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/127/mouse-movement-causes-gazebo-death/) by [cga](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/66/cga/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 223 on 2012-11-01

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [DRC_Justin](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/73/drc_justin/) on 2012-11-05**:
I have observed this issue as well, but only when running the basic Gazebo v1.2.x.  If you run the full DRCSim package including the ROS libraries, I believe this may not be as significant of a problem.  But the OSRF team can answer better than I.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

That sounds like [bug #119](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/issue/119/mousing-over-the-menu-bar-crashes-gazebo).  We believe that it was fixed in [pull request #59](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/issue/119/mousing-over-the-menu-bar-crashes-gazebo).  That fix will be included in a near-term patch release.

---

Originally posted by [gerkey](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/74/gerkey/) with karma: 1414 on 2012-11-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0